# Best way of checking if a post is in favorites list

Tags: javascript, mysql, performance, web-applications

I'm building an social media web app and i have on the database something like this:

TABLE FAVORITES:
USERID; POSTID;

And on the web app main controller something like this:

```
var posts = [{postId: x, content: 'content'}];
var favorites = [{postId: x, userid: y}];
```

But when i load all the posts (not just the favorites) on the web app i don't know whats the best way to check if a given post is in the user's favorites in order to color the heart icon embedded in it.

I have all the users favorites but what's better in terms of performance? The dumbest way to do this is to check if the postId of the given post is in any of the users favorites objects, but i think its so bad looking and poor yield.

P.S: The web app will load a minimum of 200 posts in the home view, they'll fill the screen divided in little squares. So that's why i need something good on performance, the app loads 200 posts every time user reaches the bottom of the screen.

P.S: I know that this is conceptual problem, but if anybody needs to know what language i am using its all javascript (end to end) + MySQL.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Do you need, given a post, know if it is anyone's favorite? Or to know who marked it as favorite? Basically, is the query for a specific user, or any user or all the users?

Comment: Hi Franklin. I need to know if a specific user (the one logged in and browsing) has marked it as favorite. It will only show a heart colored for this user. He will not know if anyone else has added the given post to favorite too, he'll only know if he added. How can i associate this given post with the user's favorite list to know if he has it in favorites?

Comment: And what `INDEXes` do you envision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these tables:

- **Favorites**: postId, userId
- **User**: userId, {more atts}
- **Posts**: postId, userId, {more atts}

  SELECT posts.*, IF(posts.postId IN (SELECT postID FROM Favorites WHERE userId = anId),true,false) as isFavorited FROM Posts posts LIMIT 200;

This query goes to Posts and retrieves 200 of them. If the postId is in the Favorite table for that userId (anID) then you get 1 for isFavorited, else false.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` performs poorly; reformulate as a `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks guys, helped a lot!